# Model Validation Inside Web API Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Web API method whose model needs to be late bound. The "type" of object determines the class type of a property on my model. But the "type" determinant is not in the model itself, it's in my database.

```
public class MainModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Object SubProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SubModelBase
{

}

public class SubModel1 : SubModelBase
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SubModel2 : SubModelBase
{
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

In the above models, `SubProperty` will eventually become `SubModel1`, `SubModel2`, etc.

In my action, I am doing the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Go(MainModel model)
{
    var obj = _db.GetObject(model.Id);
    SubModelBase subModel = null;
    if (obj.ObjectType == "sub-model-1")
    {
        var jObject = JObject.FromObject(model.SubProperty);
        subModel = jObject.ToObject<SubModel1>();
    }
    else if (obj.ObjectType == "sub-model-2")
    {
        var jObject = JObject.FromObject(model.SubProperty);
        subModel = jObject.ToObject<SubModel2>();
    }

    // TODO: Validate the sub object
}
```

After I have my new model, which has Data Annotations markup, how can I trigger model validation on it?

Comment: Add a check to the ModelState in your controller: `if(ModelState.IsValid) { //Rest of code }`

Comment: Are the only data annotations `Required`? Or do you have others or custom ones? If the only data annotation is `Required` then you don't need to check that on the backend.. instead it's quicker to just reference the `jQueryval` in your view.  That works with certain data annotations

Comment: @maccettura `ModelState` will only have validation results for `MainModel`. It won't have results for the sub types.

Comment: @GTown-Coder no, more (and custom) attributes are used. `[Required]` was just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.

Inside the Web API action method, I can use `ApiController.Validate<T>()` to validate my new model.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn573258%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

After that, I call `ModelState.IsValid` to determine if the model is valid.

```
base.Validate(subModel);
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // ...
}
```